# Why firefox shows <object> and internet explorer shows <iframe>?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml, iframe

Why if i use `<object>` in place for `<iframe>`, but IE shows `<iframe>` in rendered source.

Comment: Do you have the Url for that page? Could be dynamic markup generated based on a server-side browser detection. Btw, you shoud really start to accept your other questions. :)

Comment: @o.k.w @Doug Neiner - you both are right. i will surely accept some answer but if i get expected answer then i accept at the moment but if don't then i wait, i will improve my some question.

Comment: sounds good. I tried looking at the source quick on this question, but its on an ASPX page which I haven't worked extensively with in a long time. Sorry I couldn't be more help on this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE available to look right now but IE may be getting confused because you are using the XHTML1.1 doctype. Not only does IE not understand XHTML but you are 1) serving it as HTML and 2) version 1.1 is an XML only application. That's not counting the several errors the validator shows.

Answer (score 1):

The server must check the User-Agent header that the browser sends with its request. The server uses `iframe` if it looks like an Internet Explorer user-agent, and `object` for everything else (including Firefox, Chrome, and wget).

I confirmed that the browsers weren't somehow changing the code themselves by using wget and altering only its `--user-agent` argument.

As for exactly where or why the server is doing this, I can't say.